# Wrong props on client even though getServerSideProps returns properly

Tags: next.js

I have a route `/dashboard` and `/dashboard/[id].ts`.

The `getServerSideProps` of `/dashboard/[id].ts` does a database call and returns data:

```
const books = await orm.find({ library: context.params.id });

return {
  props: { books }
}
```

So now this is the problme:

1. I load `/dashboard/1` - this shows the right books on the page
2. I click button on the page to go to `/dashboard`
3. I then click button page to go to `/dashboard/2` - the problem is here. Instead of showing books that belong to id `2` its using the data that was loaded on the route I hit on first step.

Did anyone have this issue? Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: `getServerSideProps` should return object with `props` key actually. You have a typo in example or in your source code too? Another question is how you are handling this props on the client? Just showing right await or you have some store with data?

Comment: Oops thanks for that catch @Danila - that was a typo when I was creating a simplified example for stackvoerflow. In the client side I just iterate through the props right away. Do I have to await it on the client side? `export default const MyPage = props => <div>{props.books.map(....)}</div>`

Comment: Oh @Danila that was it! I was using react-query and the <QueryClient> was in the `_app`!